# Pull down to refresh in Kendo-UI, text overlaps showing both "release" and "pull" labels

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a problem with the pull down refresh. It works the first time, but then if I change to a different view, then come back to the original view, the `Pull to refresh` and `Release to refresh` text seem to get duplicated and overlapped on itself. I am "hardcoding" the datasource's data here, I don't want to use the transport ajax.

I am trying to manually update the data in the `setOptions` `pull` method, instead of letting Kendo update it via ajax. The actual data update works. There are no Javascript errors and I get the same result in Chrome and Firefox.

First time works:

[image]

After moving to another view, then back to this view, then pulling down:

[image]

My view code is:

```
<div id="subitem-view" data-role="view" data-show="showSubItems">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">

        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="subItemList" class="itemList">
    </ul>
    <script id="subItemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
       #:Name#
    </script>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showSubItems(e) {

    var subItems = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
            { Name : "Test1" },
            { Name : "Test2" }
        ] 
    });

    e.view.element.find("#subItemList").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: subItems,
        pullToRefresh: true,
        template: kendo.template($("#subItemTemplate").html())
    });

    if (typeof (e.view.scroller.pull) == "undefined") {
        e.view.scroller.setOptions({
            pull: function () {
                console.log("pull event...");

                subItems.data([
                    { Name : "Test1 Updated" },
                    { Name : "Test2 Updated" }
                ]);

                setTimeout(function () { e.view.scroller.pullHandled(); }, 400);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing your Kendo UI Mobile ListView on every View show which leads to unpredictable results, like recreating the pull to refresh labels. You should do it in the Init event only.

Comment: That solved it thanks! That had crossed my mind but using the `show` event and you use the transport ajax instead of hard coding the data, there are no problems with the pull down, strange!

Comment: The problem is that all Widgets on init add elements and events to support various features. So either you need to destroy the widget beforehand (which doesn't remove the HTML, only kills its object and events, so you have to purge the HTML too) or don't initialize it every time (which will also improve the performance).